# Casting the proper way in C++

Tags: c++, casting

I apologise if this isn't considered a good enough question (since my own solution just works, so I don't actually have a problem), but here goes.
I mean, I was brought up on C and I only learned C++ later, so maybe I'm biased, but still.

In this particular case, there is one library that returns a `const char*`, while another library needs a `void*` as input. So if I want to call the second library with the result of the first, I will need to write

```
second(const_cast<void*>(static_cast<const void*>(first())));
```

Right? That's the only proper way, right?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be passing the `const char*` to the `void*`... might lead to bugs / is not safe.

Comment: No, the second library doesn't change its input, it just wants a void* for its parameter. I'm sorry, I didn't write those libraries, nor can I change them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `char*` can be implicitly converted to a `void*`, so your code can be simplified to this:

```
second(const_cast<char*>(first()));
```

This is only safe if the definition of `second` operates *as if* its parameter had the type `const void*`.

Comment: Hey, good one. I never even thought to try that. Thanks. And yes, the second library doesn't try to change its input, so that's OK.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is all too usual that library writers forget to add all the `const` specifiers to pointer arguments, thus making it more cumbersome to use their functions. This is indeed one of the cases where you can use `const_cast` with a (relatively) easy conscience.